# How to delete tracks from Spotify using Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, spotify

I am trying to delete a song from a Spotify playlist using the Spotify API and it doesn't seem to be working. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Authorization' :'Bearer '+access,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
params={"tracks":
                {"uri":
                       ["spotify:track:2goLsvvODILDzeeiT4dAoR"]
                }
       }
remove=requests.delete("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/55J330mslu8XwOUXef77Qw/tracks",headers=headers,params=params)
```

I get a 404 error with `print(remove.json())` giving `{'error': {'status': 400, 'message': 'Missing tracks'}}`

and `print(remove.url)`gives`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/55J330mslu8XwOUXef77Qw/tracks?tracks=uri` which seems to be incomplete for some reason.

The delete endpoint seems to be working from their online test console but they use curl and they had to escape the quotes in the `params` array. I tried escaping the quotes in python and I get an error:

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character.

Below is an example that works but its from the Spotify examples that work with curl

```
curl -X "DELETE" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists//tracks" --data "{\"tracks\":[{\"uri\":\"spotify:track:2DB2zVP1LVu6jjyrvqD44z\",\"positions\":[0]},{\"uri\":\"spotify:track:5ejwTEOCsaDEjvhZTcU6lg\",\"positions\":[1]}]}" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer BQDqsVD6LMUcgDXfe8F0gupyYlqjRbIqjuJKfzfoUBL5DvA22YS2tp0-ksyFmI0YDCHgc0WZN664vNc5ZwMjm3xvJV--BiTnwn7Oki6IDIRXeWjQsIK8iNkd8PASuY4zBUxk37F2aZv29_Kg23cvNmCi5aABb5gVO2OjpjQhGwMr16Clie4qymoYoXH7PB9J3-ShZ8DzWG1y5r0GETwgi9Jj0q3A3B7KY3Xw6VnERIfQSXRw8SdkpdSpSMfPKBt4utCPXIOt2198Kw"
```

Any way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got this working. For anyone having trouble translation curl to python code there's this conversion website https://curl.trillworks.com

My code ended up as follows and everything works now:

```
params='{"tracks":[{"uri":"spotify:track:1snNAXmmPXCn0dkF9DaPWw"}]}'

remove=requests.delete("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/55J330mslu8XwOUXef77Qw/tracks",headers=headers,data=params)
```